# case statement is not working as expected in bash

Tags: bash, case, command-substitution

I was trying to match ID field of /etc/os-relase with a string value using case statement. My code is

```
chk_distro=$(grep -w "ID" /etc/os-release | awk 'BEGIN{FS="="} {print $2}')

echo "$chk_distro"

case "$chk_distro" in
    "centos" ) echo "Distro matched";;
    * ) echo "No match found";;
esac
```

My expected output is

```
"centos"
Distro matched
```

But $chk_distro is not matching with with the string "centos". Always it shows

```
"centos"
No match found
```

If I had issue with the substituted command output assigned to chk_distro variable, then it would not be correctly displayed as output of

```
echo "$chk_distro"
```

Please help me to find out the issue.

Output of `typeset -p chk_distro` is `declare -- chk_distro="\"centos\""`

Comment: `"centos"` in the output means you have quotes _as part of your data_. In `case "$chk_distro" in "centos")` the quotes are syntax, not data.

Comment: To put it differently: `centos` and `"centos"` are two different strings; they do not match each other.

Comment: Have you considered using `lsb-release` to retrieve the distro name instead of rolling your own `grep | awk` pipeline? (You can also just use `awk`; there's nothing that grep can do that awk can't do better).

Comment: please update the question to include the output from `typeset -p chk_distro` so we can see exactly what's stored in the variable

Comment: assuming you want to match on a string that *contains* the string `'centos'`: `*centos*) ...;;`

Comment: Hello @markp-fuso  I've updated with ```typeset -p chk_distro```

Answer (score 2):

As shown by the `echo`, your data contains literal quotes. Your `case` checks for a string that does not contain literal quotes.

If the only thing you want to change is the `case` statement, consider:

```
case "$chk_distro" in
    "centos" | '"centos"') echo "Distro matched";;
    *)                     echo "No match found";;
esac
```

The shell syntax `"centos"` represents the literal string `centos`, which contains no quotes.

By contrast, the shell syntax `'"centos"'` represents the literal string `"centos"`.